# How to reset default button style in Firefox 4 +

Tags: css, firefox, button, input

In firefox 3.6 you could use `::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;padding:0;margin:0;}` to remove those default margins and paddings `forms.css` added.

How can I reset this in Firefox 4? I've been searching for any .css files inside the install directory that could add styles to my button but can't find any for ff4 - the button still gets that annoying 1px top padding that won't allow the text to align to vertical middle.

http://easwee.net/other/FF_problem.gif

EDIT: I use a reset stylesheet so no need to reset styles. It's a browser stylesheet that's messing here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I actually found the solution myself.

In your url field type: `resource://gre-resources/forms.css` - this will open forms.css for FF4 - and search for the following selector

```
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="file"] > input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner
```

Now just put that in your main stylesheet like:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="file"] > input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;padding:0;margin:0;}
```

It shouldn't be overriding your css anymore. Also note that if you haven't defined any font style for your inputs FF won't inherit body font styling.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, finding those css resource files is no longer applicable in Firefox 6; however, this resolved my issue still.

Comment: @PatrickRobertSheaO'Connor In ff6 it got changed to `resource://gre-resources/html.css`

Comment: +1 so many thanks... it was too frustrating trying to figure out the persistent border..

Comment: Thanks, was burned by this myself. A minor note though: margin:0 seems unnecessary as Firefox doesn't define it itself.

Comment: @Damir Zekić Maybe in latest versions - in older it is needed.

Comment: A year later, I would suggest to have a look at Bootstrap's `reset.less` which goes a long way towards harmonizing browser quirks for forms. Also see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10108303/593036) below.

Comment: In the Developer Tools in the Inspector in the Computed tab it shows the style being affected and has a link for opening the forms.css file. I found this question by searching for "resource://gre-resources/forms.css".

Answer (score 1):

try setting it's values to undefined (`border:undefined` etc). not sure here, but it worked for me when I had a similiar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter Bootstrap does it like this in its [`reset.less`](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/reset.less) (which is a more *barebones* version of [`normalize.css`](http://github.com/necolas/normalize.css)):

```
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner { // Inner padding and border oddities in FF3/4
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

As an aside, Bootstrap's `reset.less` is probably a more reliable and perennial solution to achieve form cross-browser-ness than maintaining your own rules. It's much more complete than Meyer's `reset.css`, but more minimalist than `normalize.css`.

Answer (score 0):

just use a css reset stylesheet, that will reset all the default css for most browsers

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

or read this stackeoverflow Q&A

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset

Comment: No it won't. I'm using a reset stylesheet. Read the question again to get what I'm reffering to.

Comment: yes but even if you find that css file in firefox the change will still only apply to you and nobody else

Comment: It will apply to everyone once I find which selector is adding that and I override it with a more specified selector in my  main stylesheet. It always worked in all FF versions till now.

Comment: oh yes I see. Well looks like you found it :)

Comment: Yeah - maybe my question was bit unclear - edited few words for future if anyone searches for this.