# Position of text in a submit button

Tags: html, css

The position of the text on the search submit button on [my blog](http://eligrey.com/blog/) is very low in Firefox 4, but not Chrome 10 or IE9. I've tried almost everything, and nothing works except lowering the font size of the text, which isn't an optimal solution as the text will be too small.

### Screenshots

Firefox 4 on Windows 7:

[image: Firefox 4 screenshot]

Google Chrome 10.0.648.204 on Windows 7:

[image: Google Chrome screenshot]

The relevant HTML:

```
<form method="get" class="searchform" action="http://eligrey.com/blog"> 
    <input type="search" placeholder="search" name="s" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="&#128269;" title="Search" /> 
</form>
```

The relevant CSS rule (from http://eligrey.com/blog/wp-content/themes/eligrey.com/style.css):

```
.searchform input[type="submit"] {
    font-family: "rfhb-lpmg";
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 3em;
    background-color: #959595;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    height: 34px;
    width: 42px;
    line-height: 34px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-transition-property: border, background-color, box-shadow;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-property: border, background-color, box-shadow;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

rfhb-lpmg is just a custom font I made which implements U+2767 rotated floral heart bullet and U+1F50E right-pointing magnifying glass with simplistic glyphs.

Comment: Have you tried the `vertical-align` property?

Comment: I've tried `vertical-align:middle` with the appropriate table values for `display` and it didn't work.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I can reproduce this in FF4 on OSX 10.6, but not on my Win 7 machine. Perhaps it's because I have [gdipp](http://code.google.com/p/gdipp/) installed... Also, great work on the glyphs. I'm a big proponent of icons as web fonts.

Comment: not sure it will work or not. Put it in a div and apply css to that div. That worked many times for me.

Comment: I believe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679952/input-type-submit-text-vertical-alignment-in-firefox) has a more elegant solution to the problem. Just for the record!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've deduced that the main trouble is the `line-height` property.

Both browsers attempt to vertically center all text on buttons.  In combination with the `height` property, however, if there is not enough room to render the full standard line-height (glyph padding grows quite large with large font sizes), both browsers will pin the glyph to the top of the button, trimming the bottom.

Normally, the `line-height` would help adjust this, and in Chrome, in your example, this was successful.  However, in the case of `button` and `input type="submit"` elements, Firefox ignores **line-height** altogether, so it can't be used in this way to "fix" the positioning of the character. Using the extreme example below, we can see that the text has been pushed out of visbility in Chrome, while it still stays right in the (vertical) center in Firefox.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
input {
    border:1px solid black; 
    line-height:1000px;
    height:40px;
}
</style>
<input type="submit" value="Test"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**Firefox**: [image: Firefox]
**Chrome**: [image: Chrome]

When a button element is left to the native style (remove the `border`), `line-height` is ignored by both browsers (weirdly, Chrome also ignores the height but Firefox does not). As soon as the button is custom-styled, Chrome picks up the `line-height` but Firefox does not.

---

**So what can you do?**

If you still want to make use of CSS fonts...

1. First of all, make sure your font renders the glyphs in the same vertical-alignment that a standard font displays a basic full-height character, like `H`. *(It appears you've done this for the most part, since your page looks significantly better than the screenshots in the question.)*
2. Second, you'll notice that if you use a font like Arial, and display an H (at the same font size), it's also low.  This is because the *built in standard line-height of the font* gives it quite a bit of room above the character.  This indicates that you may have some success if you can **edit the font to trim this,** thereby giving the character enough room to not be trimmed at the bottom by the browser.
3. Probably less ideal to you, but still an option, you can use other elements, either in combination with or in place of the `button/submit` element, to get the character into place.

---

**Alternative option**

I'm not sure what your goal is in using CSS fonts, but often it is for some form of *progressive enhancement/graceful degradation*.  In this case, although (as you said in the comments) the special character is a standardized Unicode "right-pointing magnifying glass", it still will not have any meaning to the user if it doesn't *render.*

Given that the benefit of graceful degradation is to allow simpler technologies to display your website without appearing broken, the use of this character seems suspect — without CSS fonts or a native font with this character, it will render as 🔍 a `?`, or simply a blank box.

A better option for graceful degradation, given this problem, would be to simply use a **background-image**.  Make the text of the button "Search", hide the text (through CSS), and apply the background image, and then you have *actual* graceful degradation, and a fancy character for better browsers.

A background image *could* also (obviously dependent on the files themselves) have other benefits, such as faster load and render times (for instance, if a developer wanted to use a single character from a full-character-set font).

Comment: +1: The graceful degradation note is good. I would definitely use this solution over my own, but wanted to find a workaround for the Firefox issue :)

Comment: "the special character won't mean anything without CSS fonts" U+1F50E isn't a private use character. It actually means 'right-pointing magnifying glass' which implies search. Edit: Also, the character is not lower-set than normal fonts. Can you give me an example of a font that sets U+1F50E much higher? I have it right on the appropriate baseline.

Comment: I think I will be modifying my font anyways though for Firefox.

Comment: Also, "such as faster load and render times" are both incorrect. This two-glyph font is has a very light filesize (more so than an SVG or image) that I can fit in a very small data: URI, and the computations needed to render a single glyph have infinitesimal cost.

Comment: @Eli I didn't want to clutter the comments here, so I incorporated some significant changes, given your responses, into the answer itself.

Comment: Is the FF bug number known? It would help to vote on that bugzilla entry!

Answer (score 7):

FF4 sets it's own styles on input elements. You can check all of them if you paste this in your URL field:

```
resource://gre-resources/forms.css
```

Alternatively you can see this styles if you check Show user agent CSS from Style tab dropdown if you have Firebug instaled.

Check solution here: [How to reset default button style in Firefox 4 +](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459893/how-to-reset-default-button-style-in-firefox-4)

Answer (score 3):

I came to the same conclusion as Renesis, though I wasn't sure whether Firefox wasn't respecting line-height or vertical-align. Here is the outline to a different solution that allows you to continue to use your fancy glyph. Since you are using pixel-sizes for your button, try something along these lines (simplified html). This might be overkill, and a background-image would almost certainly be more appropriate, but anyway.

The simplified html:

```
<div class="searchform">
  <input type="search" placeholder="search" name="s"  />
  <span><input type="submit" value="&#128269;" title="Search" /></span>
</div>
```

And the simplified css:

```
// hide the border and background for the submit button
.searchform input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}
// give the span the properties that the submit button has now
span {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px; // or whatever
  height: 30px; // or whatever
}
// absolutely position the submit button
.searchform input[type="submit"] {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -15px; // half the span height
  margin-left: -15px; // half the span width
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had been facing a similar problem when using CSS inside buttons. The text was offset by 1 pixel in firefox, and rest of the browsers it was just fine. I used "padding" property specific to Firefox, in the following way

The original code in which the input button's text was one pixel lower in Firefox

```
.mybutton { 
    height:32px; background-color:green; 
    font-size:14px; color:white; font-weight:bold; 
    border:0px; -moz-border-radius:16px; border-radius:16px;
}
```

and after adding the Firefox specific padding after the above css, it was perfect in Firefox

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .mybutton { padding-bottom:1px; }
}
```

In your case, may be you need a bit more padding-bottom, and probably padding-top in negative too (-1px or -2px).

Answer (score 2):

I came across this when I was looking for a solution to this problem, but since I never really found anything other than a hint at changing the padding bottom I wanted to share that I found adjusting the padding-bottom for just firefox worked great.

Every other browser allowed for enough line-height control to adjust the text positioning.

```
/* This gets picked up in firefox only to adjust the text into the middle */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    input[type="button"],
    input[type="submit"],
    button.btn {
        padding-bottom: 6px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had something like  this happen earlier this week - I found out that you have to apply certain ccs elements to the 'parent' element instead of the 'child'. So basically try some of the css like vertical-align: in the .searchform div.

Meanwhile, I'm having trouble with my search icon at smartemini.com. It works in aaaaallllll browsers except ie9. :(

Comment: This doesn't help as it's text inside the submit button that needs repositioning, and not the submit button itself.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same.
I was able to solve my issues, pushing padding from the bottom (!)

```
padding: 0 0 2px 0; /* total height: 36px */
height: 34px;
```

or, in a bigger picture, if you fancy consistent input['..'] and anchor button, use distinct overriding tweaking for the latter for full control.

```
/* general button styling for input and anchor buttons */
.buttonXS, .buttonS, .buttonM, .buttonL  {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px; /* just a precaution, likely ignored in FF */

    padding: 0 0 2px 0; /* total height: 36px */
    height: 34px;   
    ...
}

/* distinct vertical align for anchor buttons */
a.buttonXS, a.buttonS, a.buttonM, a.buttonL  {
    padding: 12px 0 0 0; /* total height: 36px */
    height: 24px;
}
```

(the 'T-shirt-sizes' lead to different background-offsets and widths elsewhere)

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing here is how differently browsers render text inside button elements when space is tight. Chrome centers the test vertically, while Firefox top-aligns it.

On top of that, you're using a home-made font, that might have some latent issues when it comes to vertical-height/leading/etc.

I note that when I add any other character to the `input`'s `value` - the magnifying glass drops down even further in Firefox. This suggests that tweaking the font somehow (like vertical-position, or cropping away top/bottom white-space) might help.

If that fails you should change your `<input type="submit"/>` into a `<button type="search" title="Tooltip">Label</button>` element, and see if styling the `button` is any easier than styling the `input`.

If the problem still remains, you'll need to switch tactics and wrap your button in a `<div class="btnwrap" />`.

```
.searchform .btnwrap {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  /* plus the border-radius styles */
}
.searchform button {
  /* all the original button styles, except the border */
  height: 50px;
  margin: -9px 0; /* (32-50)/2 = -9 */
}
```

(BTW, You can alternatively inner-wrap `button` text in a `<span/>` and do similar negative-margin hack to that, although I suspect that getting the vertical-centering is easier with the `button` inside a`div`.)

That said, you really should just use a good old fashioned background image replacement - it will both render and load faster. :-)

Good luck!

Comment: Using `button` instead of `input` doesn't help, it appears to be susceptible to the same text position issues.

Comment: Yes. Fixing the font seems to be the key to this fun little problem. Of course, using a background-image is by far fastest/easiest, but I have a feeling Ely knew that and just wanted to try out this approach as an experiment.

Answer (score 0):

This problem only happens on Firefox 4/Win7 with **DirectWrite** enabled render mode (which is enabled by default). Firefor4 GDI render mode is working properly.

It might caused by the **vertical-align** attribute is *baseline*. But the baseline of U1F50D sin't on the lowest point. Maybe you should try to move the font points a little higher, set the lowest point's y point to 0.

Answer (score 0):

lots of anwsers here... i think this is the simplest way to do this :

```
.searchform input[type="submit"]
{
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Hope this helps =D

Answer (score 0):

I have found that a combination of padding and line-height does the trick. As stated Firefox ignores line-height.

1. Make sure you set a larger bottom padding than top padding. Fiddle around with it a bit and you will be able to vertically align the text in Firefox.
2. You will then see that this pushes the text too close to the top of the element in Webkit. Now use a large line-height to align it properly in Webkit and voila!

I have tested this on a Windows 7 machine running Firefox 7, Chrome 16, Safari 5.1 and IE9.