# Center vertical in Firefox

Tags: css

I have a very simple button. The text appears right centered vertically respect the square when you see it in Safari or Chrome. But in Firefox the text is not centered vertically (it looks down) How to solve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/yyL5T/5/

HTML:

```
<div class="buy">mmmmm</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family:Tahoma;
  color:#fff; 
  font-size:11px; 
  letter-spacing:1px;
}

.buy {
  position:absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height:20px;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#bbb;
}
```

Comment: `vertical-align` is meant for inline elements, not for containers. You're treating it like `<td valign="center">`

Comment: It looks fine to me on firefox.

Comment: The fiddles look fine in FF 12 for me.

Comment: When the jsFiddle links go dead, this question is totally useless.  Please re-work your question to expand your explanation and include your code.

Comment: This similar question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599343/position-of-text-in-a-submit-button

Comment: If you remove the vertical-aling nothing changes. This is not the point

Comment: In Firefox and in a mac there is more space on the top that on the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Firefox have some problems to center text when the div is not very high. (I don't know why). In this specific case: font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 11px; the div needs to be 23px or more if we want it to be well centered in the div

```
.buy {
  position:absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 25px; /* this is what changes */
  line-height:25px; /* this is what changes */
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#bbb;
}
```

Playing here: http://jsfiddle.net/yyL5T/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
.comprar {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#bbb;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```