# ASP.Net TextBox and Input Button not aligning in FF using CSS

Tags: css, webforms

I am not able to align textbox and Input Button control on an asp.net web form using CSS. I am not sure what property of css is compatible with all the browser.

Please check out example on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PWK7V/

Same comes aligned in IE and Chrome but input button appears slightly 1 pixel higher in Firefox 11.0.

I made changes in properties also. i am not sure how i can fix this as i am not a CSS guru.

I would appreciate if some can fix this and point out the problem so that i can keep that in mind for future.

Comment: I hope this solution works for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557784/persistent-margin-and-1px-height-difference-around-input-elements

Comment: @Nestenius It is a workable solution. I wish we could simple fix it with css properties. So it seem it is browser issue and we have to use a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution based given by @Nestenuis**

Working example

http://jsfiddle.net/PWK7V/33/

Comment: Bravo, I believed you've fixed it. Is it still a problem?

Comment: @Nestenuis, I used your solution.. Unfortunately i cant mark your solution as correct as it is part of "comment" not Answer. Thanks..