# How to style button inputs to be identical in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, button

Take a look at [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/SnZX2/2/) in Chrome and FireFox.

In Chrome, the button should be a tad smaller than in FireFox. I have added the solution CSS from [How to reset default button style in Firefox 4 +](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5459893/388916) (which made the button a little smaller) but the button is still bigger in FireFox. The difference isn't very visible in this example, but have a look at how it affects my design.

Chrome:
[image: Chrome screenshot]

FireFox:
[image: FireFox screenshot]

As you can see the button is thicker in FireFox and is affecting the layout. Is there any way of avoiding this short of using styled divs in place of buttons?

---

Also, I'm using Meyer's CSS reset stylesheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have concluded that the only way of ensuring that button/submit inputs remain identical across browsers is to recreate them using divs. Creating button inputs is easy since you can attach click events onto divs the same way as on buttons. Creating submit inputs is barely any harder. I solved it using jQuery by declaring a class, for instance 'submit', and adding the submit button functionality to all elements that have that class on load. Here's an exampe:

```
// On page load:
$('.submit').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Divs with the *submit* class that are not in a form will do nothing when clicked.

If you add `tabindex="n"` (where `n` is a number) to the element, it can also be focused using tab, just like a normal button. You can also style it to show that it's focused by using the `:focus` css pseudo-class. Then you could use space or enter to click the button with this event handler:

```
$('.submit').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32)
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

<sub>(I wrote that last snippet in a hurry and haven't actually tested it. If you find an error in it or test it successfully please edit this answer accordingly.)</sub>

Comment: +1; I hate the fact that browsers make it difficult to style inputs, because I hate recreating all that functionality from scratch. I don't recommend doing this, but sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do. Also, 
extremely minor semantic improvement, use `$(this).closest('form').submit();`

Comment: Yeah I just read the documentation on both functions, and `closest` is a much better fit for this task. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Does keybord focus with the tab key and the pressing enter work with this?

Comment: @OskarBerggren Not automatically, you have to add `tabindex="n"` to the button and a few extra lines of JavaScript. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Hubro Great, thanks, so many web sites fail to respect de facto standards on this.

Answer (score 10):

Firefox adds a special padding to `input`s and `button` elements. This takes care of it:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner, 
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner, 
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner, 
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: 0 none !important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. -moz-focus-inner is usually what creates the discrepancy between button sizes across browsers. Didn't read through the whole question tbh.

Answer (score 2):

Have you by any chance set a `line-height` on the buttons on your page? You haven't on the fiddle, but `line-height`'s other than normal, aren't accepted on firefox, and some other browser I believe - maybe IE, I'm not sure.

Comment: I haven't touched the `line-height` property. Good thought, but why would that also affect the width of the button?

Comment: On the image the widths don't seem changed to me. Perhaps they are. I'm not sure.

Comment: Is your page online? I could take a look at it.

Comment: Alas, it is not. But the styles used and issues experienced is identical to the JSFiddle example I provided in my question

Comment: I'm not experiencing the issue with the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a CSS reset? I dont have FF on this computer or else I would check if this works.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.5.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">
```

Comment: I'm already using one, edited it in to my question. Also, JSFiddle normalizes CSS by default.