# Applying same styling to an <input> and an <a> tag results to different layout

Tags: html, css, firefox, button

I have a CSS class for styling buttons. When I apply it to an `<input>` and an `<a>` tag, the `<a>` is a bit smaller than the `<input>`. This problem occurs in Firefox (33), but in Chrome (38) it looks fine.

Here is a minimal example:

```css
.my-button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
        
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
        
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
    
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<input class="my-button" type="submit" value="Save">
<a class="my-button" href="#">Cancel</a>
```

You can see it also here: http://jsfiddle.net/tr4vbrha/4/

Comment: The answer to the suggested duplicate question is to recreate the buttons with divs using javascript, which I believe is a very dirty solution.

Comment: You read the wrong answer. [Read again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11605890/1493698). Or if you have trouble finding the correct answer, [see a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvaj578e/).

Comment: OK, thanks. This seems to solve it for both Firefox and Chrome, however the `padding: 0 !important;` is not required [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvaj578e/1/).
Could this be a bug that should be reported to Firefox?

Comment: That answer is just an overkill. Just pick the one that works and move on. And no, this is not a bug. The fact that Firefox has its own margin that can be targeted via prefixed selectors are most likely a hack. What we are doing here is just to unhack the hack.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of a difference in font. The `input` on windows is `Microsoft Sans Serif`, while in the `a` tag it is `Times New Roman`.

To fix this add the `font-family` property to the my-button class.

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem, adding `font-family: Arial;` doesn't change anything: http://jsfiddle.net/tr4vbrha/7/

Comment: I saw the difference in Firefox too and when I added code font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;  They look the same.

Comment: On Mac OSX Firefox 33.1 and on Ubuntu 14.04 Firefox 33.0 the problem occurs no matter the font-family. I cannot verify for Windows though. In Safari 7.1 it works fine.

Comment: Yes I noticed, sorry I thought it would be it

Answer (score 1):

This probably is because the box-sizing property of button is different to that of a button. I added this:

```css
input{
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.my-button{
    min-width: 2.75em;
}
```

and it worked

Comment: It doesn't seem to change something: http://jsfiddle.net/tr4vbrha/10/ None of the `box-sizing` values at the input tag changes something.

Comment: First: I forgot that -moz- is needed before box sizing.

Comment: Second: Using develop tools it worked with 2.75em but saving it to a file it worked with 3em(the diff is one pixel). I don't know why it doesn work on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

remove css attribure : display:inline-block
see example :[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ax55302q/2/)

```css
.my-button {

    padding: 1em;
    
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: none;

    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #000;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .my-button {
        display:inline-block
    }
}
```

```html
<input class="my-button" type="submit" value="Save">
<a href="#" class="my-button">Cancel</a>
```

Comment: They look differently to me in the fiddle (Firefox on Windows). The cancel button is 1px higher than the save button.

Comment: In Firefox (Ubuntu) your demo works, but in Chrome, the `<input>` tag is now smaller than the `<a>`.

Comment: now please check..............