# Why is a button without a border in Firefox two pixel higher than line-height?

Tags: css

I've a Button with the following super simple css:

```
button {
  background: #005eb8;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

"line-hight" is set to 50px. But the button is (in Firefox) 52px - I expected it to be 50. Is there any reason for that? In chrome the height is 50 as expected...

Code at JSBIN:
http://jsbin.com/jagiviyima/9?html,output

Comment: have you set margin:0; on your button?

Comment: Add height: 50px to the button styling.

Comment: @jbutler483: Yes I added "?html,output" that you can see the code

Comment: as @chrisbedoya told you, you are using line-height instead of height, check another related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7856737/4316870

Comment: The use of line-height was intended. But the defaults of -moz-focus-inner was my problem - as people below pointed out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
   border: none;
   padding:0;
}
```

Add such css rule.

Comment: Wow! That works.
I've spend now hours on this - but I never though about focus-inner ...?! :-=) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You ask - is there some reason for that - I believe it is. I don't have Firefox at hand now, but you are using `button` html element and buttons typically have some default css rules applied to them across the browsers (these are obviously browser specific). My guess is FF is adding some default `padding`, `margin`, `border` or something of that kind to your own defined style. Try setting these to 0 explicitly.

A bit of googling yielded [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11605890/3242721) which exlains the issue in a more detail, proposed resolution is:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner, 
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0 !important;
    border: 0 none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the explanation. Yes it was focus inner! Mr Posia was faster :-)